# Where is my ./configure file in OSX 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: terminal, macos

I'm setting up [Cap'n Pro](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/install.html) on my Mac and the install instructions ask me to type the following in terminal:

```
./configure CXX=$HOME/clang-3.2/bin/clang++
```

I look in my user folder i.e. ~/./configure but it doesn't exist. Am I doing this right? Where is my ./configure folder? Do I need to create one?

Also, yes I have invisible folders visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `configure` script (not directory) is part of the source code archive you should have downloaded (`capnproto-c++-X.Y.Z.tar.gz`).

When you unpack that archive, change to the toplevel directory (`capnproto-X-Y-Z`) and run the configure command.

```
$ cd [to where you downloaded the archive]
$ tar xzf capnproto-c++-X.Y.Z.tar.gz
$ cd capnproto-c++-X.Y.Z
$ ./configure CXX=$HOME/clang-3.2/bin/clang++
```

Then run the subsequent commands (`make` and `sudo make install`) from that same directory.

This is rather generic - most autotool-based builds work exactly like that.